# Android Studio - Code Generate only shows copyright as option

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I am working on a Java file in Android and I click on code, generate I usually have many options to choose from. Now it only shows the copyright option.

[image: Code Generate Only Shows Copyright]

Comment: What are some of the "many options to choose from" that you usually see?  Which one in particular are you looking for here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the android studio.
you should try this inside your class.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in an area that is actually part of your class body.